# Populating matrix with values from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix of samples by genes (mat1) that looks like:

```
      | Sample 1 | Sample 2 | ...
Gene 1|    NA    |     NA   |
Gene 2|    NA    |     NA   |
Gene 3|    NA    |     NA   |
  ...
```

and a dataframe with all samples that have each gene:

```
|   Gene   |  Sample  |
| Gene 1   | Sample 2 |
| Gene 2   | Sample 2 |
| Gene 2   | Sample 3 |
| Gene 2   | Sample 4 |
    ...         ...
```

I would like to use the values from df2 to fill the matrix with 1 if the gene is present in the sample. Something like :

```
       | Sample 1 | Sample 2 | Sample 3 | Sample 4|
Gene 1 |    NA    |     1    |   NA     |   NA    |
Gene 2 |    NA    |     1    |    1     |    1    |
```

I am struggling to find way to do this. Is there a good method to do this on a large dataset?

The closest I have gotten is:

```
finalmat <- for (i in 1:nrow(mat1)) mat1[i,df2$Samples[[i]]]<-df2$Gene[[i]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Using `xtabs(~Gene+Sample, df2)` will probably get you pretty close. It will use 0 rather than NA and will increase in number if more than on occur, but you could easy modify it the results if you like.

Comment: Greetings! Instead of tables of your data, usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the empty matrix to start. You can get your target output with:

```r
table(df2$Gene, df2$Sample)
#>         
#>          Sample 2 Sample 3 Sample 4
#>   Gene 1        1        0        0
#>   Gene 2        1        1        1
```

---

**Data used**

```r
df2 <- data.frame(Gene   = paste('Gene', c(1, 2, 2, 2)), 
                  Sample = paste('Sample', c(2, 2, 3, 4)))

df2
#>     Gene   Sample
#> 1 Gene 1 Sample 2
#> 2 Gene 2 Sample 2
#> 3 Gene 2 Sample 3
#> 4 Gene 2 Sample 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>